# Troubles with immersive mode in Android

Tags: java, android

I am developing an application which can be in two modes: default mode with action bar and fullscreen. User can switch from default mode to fullscreen mode and back.
 And now I want to hide the software system buttons on tabs running under Android KitKat and older. To do this I am using immersive mode. When user is switching into fullscreen mode I am running this code:

```
mDecorView.setSystemUiVisibility(
        View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION // hide nav bar
        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN // hide status bar
        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE);
```

When user switches back  into normal mode, I am running this code:

```
 mDecorView.setSystemUiVisibility(
        View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN);
```

First problem is in that when I am switching into immersive mode, my view doesn't resizing and  I can see a piece of background of my window instead of software buttons (Picture 1).

[image]

The second problem is in that, when I am switching back from fullscreen mode into default mode my view also doesn't resizing and actionbar and software buttons are overflowing my view. (Picture 2)

[image]